# why need call _siftdown at the end of the func _siftup in python moudle heapq

Tags: python, heapq

I am reading the source code of heapq, and found that the _siftup func called _siftdown at last. I think it is a bit redundant.
I want to to known that is this really necessary?

I did a test bwtween the two condition, but I did not find any difference between the two condition. the test code is below (the heap_test is a copy of heap and commented the last line of _sifup):

```py
from heapq_test import heapify as heapify_test

import heapq
import random

for _ in range(200000):
    a = [random.randint(0, 30) for _ in range(100)]
    b = a.copy()
    heapify_test(a)
    heapq.heapify(b)
    assert a == b
```

Answer (score 2):

The last _siftdown at _siftup func is necessary. An example helps.

heap = [1,1,1,3,4,5,1]

if you delete the last _siftdown in _siftup and do the heappop() you get [1, 1, 5, 3, 4, 1] which is not a heap.

The last _siftdown is necessary, because the while loop in below code(from the heapq source code) **just pick the smaller child but didn't compare the newitem's value with child**, so in the last we need a _siftdown. And why the author implement _siftup function in this way? and why it continues to find the smaller child until a leaf is hit in _siftup? you can get these in the author comment above the _siftup function in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/heapq.py).

```py
def _siftup(heap, pos):
    endpos = len(heap)
    startpos = pos
    newitem = heap[pos]
    # Bubble up the smaller child until hitting a leaf.
    childpos = 2*pos + 1    # leftmost child position
    while childpos < endpos:
        # Set childpos to index of smaller child.
        rightpos = childpos + 1
        if rightpos < endpos and not heap[childpos] < heap[rightpos]:
            childpos = rightpos
        # Move the smaller child up.
        heap[pos] = heap[childpos]
        pos = childpos
        childpos = 2*pos + 1
    # The leaf at pos is empty now.  Put newitem there, and bubble it up
    # to its final resting place (by sifting its parents down).
    heap[pos] = newitem
    _siftdown(heap, startpos, pos)
```

Hope this reply helps you.

Comment: seems `[1,1,1,3,4,5,1]` is not a heap?  thanks rookie for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

The func `_siftup` is optimized in heapq sourcecode, the implementation in this way that just **Bubble up the smaller child until hitting a leaf and _siftdown finnaly** can cut the number of comparisions a little than normal way (just `_siftup` and compare parent with left_child, right_child every time).

Comment: could you show me an example, i am still confused. thanks